# When I log mixedCategory is firstName[object Object]lastName, How to insert icon inside a string

Tags: reactjs

```
state = { icon: , }

loadAllCategories = async () => 
{ 
  const{icon} = this.state; 
  firstCategory ="Electronic Devices";
  lastCategory = "Phone"; mixedCategory =firstCategory+ icon + lastCategory;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return as a jsx value as shown below, for wrapping you can use [React.Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```
let mixedCategory = (
  <>
    {firstCategory} {icon} {lastCategory}
  </>
);
```

Code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Icon = () => {
  return (
    <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle
        cx="50"
        cy="50"
        r="40"
        stroke="black"
        stroke-width="3"
        fill="red"
      />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  state = { icon: <Icon />, mixedValue: null };

  loadAllCategories = () => {
    const { icon } = this.state;
    let firstCategory = "Electronic Devices";
    let lastCategory = "Phone";
    let mixedCategory = (
      <>
        {firstCategory} {icon} {lastCategory}
      </>
    );
    this.setState({
      mixedValue: mixedCategory
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.loadAllCategories}>Click here</button>
        {this.state.mixedValue && this.state.mixedValue}
      </>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

see the working example in the [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-morning-2dfro)

**@Update**

as mentioned in the comments using FontAwesomIcon

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { fab } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import { faInfo, faCoffee } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

library.add(fab, faInfo, faCoffee);

class App extends Component {
  state = { icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon="info" />, mixedValue: null };

  loadAllCategories = () => {
    const { icon } = this.state;
    let firstCategory = "Electronic Devices";
    let lastCategory = "Phone";
    let mixedCategory = (
      <>
        {firstCategory} {icon} {lastCategory}
      </>
    );
    this.setState({
      mixedValue: mixedCategory
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.loadAllCategories}>Click here</button>
        {this.state.mixedValue && this.state.mixedValue}
      </>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/string-and-fontawesomeicon-together-fzopz)

Comment: Thank for your advice, but I need to know how to change font awesome icon to your icon function

Comment: so instead of custom function you are using FontAwesomIcon ? is  thats the case

Comment: Let me know if you are checking for the FontAwesomIcon so i will be able to help you and update the answer

Comment: Added new code for using FontAwesomeIcon, kindly upvote and accept if the question has been answered. Also please mention in the question so it will be helpful for the future users . Happy coding :)